# Use Multiple Database Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is my Use Case,

On Some Models, Users connect to different database on Different Hosts. Using establish_connection thus,

```
#charge.rb
cattr_accessor :ip_address
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter => "postgresql", :database => Rails.application.config.database_name, :host => ip_address,
                                       :username => Rails.application.config.database_user, :password => Rails.application.config.database_password })
```

My Question,How can i set :host, dynimically from the charges_controller.rb? Every other argument in the establish_connection method is "Fixed".

Tried using a before_filter in the Application Controller to set the value to ip_address to no avail. Also tried using initialize on the charge model(though a bad idea) to no avail. :host, returns nil

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'c' in your virtual attribute `attr_accessor :host` and then insert the value into your params hash while in the controller before passing to the model with those params.  For example:

In your typical controller you would have something like:

```
def create
 @charge = Charge.create(charge_params)
 @charge.connect_to_proper_host(host)
end 

private

def charge_params
  params.require(:charge).permit( :at1 , :some_other_att, :host)
end
```

**UPDATE**

You can set this method in your model and then reference it on the newly created object in your controller:

```
    def connect_to_proper_database(host)
       self.host = host
       #Note, You don't need to define self.host if you dont plan on reusing this variable throughout other methods in the model and can instead reference it by simply "host" in that case.
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter => "postgresql", :database => Rails.application.config.database_name, :host => self.host, :username => Rails.application.config.database_user,:password => Rails.application.config.database_password })
    end
```